# python tkinter - get cursor in new window

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, cursor

I'd like to use the tab key in both showing of the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk() 
def pressButton():
        main.destroy()
End=Button(main,text='Finished',width=15,command=pressButton).grid()
main.mainloop()

from tkinter import *
main = Tk() 
def pressButton():
        main.destroy()
End=Button(main,text='Finished',width=15,command=pressButton).grid()
main.mainloop()
```

first window works: i can press tab and space and it opens the second window; there i'm not able to "press button" by using tab and space, because the cursor is in Python Shell. 
How can I get the cursor in the second window?

Comment: Window focus is handled by your window manager, I'd be surprised if tkinter (or you) could influence where the keyboard focus goes.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating one tkinter program that creates two instances of `Tk`, so the question doesn't make much sense. If you want more than one window you should create instances of `Toplevel` to create additional windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in that post ["Tkinter main window focus"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751100/tkinter-main-window-focus), it is possible to force the focus to the main window.

**Solution** - add a call to the `after()` to `focus_force()`.

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk() 
def pressButton():
    main.destroy()
End=Button(main,text='Finished',width=15,command=pressButton).grid()
# call the focus_force() after the window is displayed
main.after(1, lambda: main.focus_force())
main.mainloop()
```