# Python Windows Key Press Simulation Issue: Printing Single Quote Instead of Question Mark

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working on a Python script to simulate key presses in a Windows environment using ctypes. The script is intended to type out a given string, replacing certain characters with their corresponding key presses. However, I am encountering an issue where, instead of printing a question mark ('?'), the script prints a single quote (''). I have tried adjusting the virtual key codes and ASCII values, but the problem persists.

I have included the relevant code below. Any insights into why this issue might be occurring or suggestions for a resolution would be greatly appreciated.

```
import ctypes
import time

# Constants for virtual key codes
VK_SPACE = 0x20
VK_BACK = 0x08
VK_COMMA = 0xBC
VK_PERIOD = 0xBE
VK_SINGLE_QUOTE = 0xDE  # Virtual key code for single quote (')
VK_SHIFT = 0x10
VK_OEM_1 = 0xBA  # Virtual key code for the ';:' key
VK_OEM_2 = 0xBF  # Virtual key code for the '/?' key

# Function to simulate key press using Windows API
def press_key(virtual_key, key_down=True, key_up=False):
    if key_down:
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(virtual_key, 0, 0, 0)
    if key_up:
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(virtual_key, 0, 2, 0)

# Function to simulate pressing the shift key
def press_shift():
    press_key(VK_SHIFT)

# Function to simulate releasing the shift key
def release_shift():
    press_key(VK_SHIFT, key_down=False, key_up=True)

# Function to simulate typing a string
def simulate_typing(input_string):
    try:
        
        time.sleep(5)

        # Simulate typing with key presses and spaces
        for char in input_string:
            if char == ' ':
                press_key(VK_SPACE)
            elif char == ',':
                press_key(VK_COMMA)
            elif char == '.':
                press_key(VK_PERIOD)
            elif char == "'":
                press_key(VK_SINGLE_QUOTE)  # Virtual key code for single quote
            elif char == '!':
                press_shift()
                press_key(0x31)  # Virtual key code for '1' to simulate '!'
                release_shift()
            elif char == '?':
                press_shift()
                press_key(0xBF)  # Virtual key code for the question mark on German keyboards
                release_shift()
            else:
                # Check if the character is uppercase and press the shift key accordingly
                if char.isupper():
                    press_shift()
                if char == '/':
                    press_key(VK_OEM_2)  # Virtual key code for '/?' to simulate '/'
                else:
                    press_key(ord(char.upper()))
                if char.isupper():
                    release_shift()

        print(f"Typed: {input_string}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        text_to_type = "Hello, World! How are you doing?"

        # Call the function to simulate typing
        simulate_typing(text_to_type)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nScript execution interrupted by user.")
```

**What I've Tried:**
I have attempted to address the issue by modifying the virtual key codes and ASCII values in the script. Specifically, I've experimented with using the virtual key code for the single quote (VK_OEM_7) and the ASCII value for the single quote (ord("'")). Additionally, I tried using the virtual key code for the question mark (VK_OEM_2) to simulate typing it.

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected the script to correctly simulate typing a question mark ('?') when encountering the character '?' in the input string. Conversely, when the script encounters the single quote character (''), it should simulate typing a single quote. However, despite these adjustments, the script consistently prints a single quote regardless of the input character.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: An alternative way is to send unicode characters directly instead of simulating key presses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910555/252218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two changes:

```
def press_key(virtual_key, key_down=True, key_up=True):
#                                                ^^^^
```

Above so calling `press_key` presses and releases the key by default.

```
def press_shift():
    press_key(VK_SHIFT, key_up=False)
#                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Above so calling `press_shift` doesn't release the key due to the first change.

Then the code works properly:

```
Typed: Hello, World! How are you doing?

C:\>Hello, World! How are you doing?
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205935/235698) for the recommended way to send input.  [`keybd_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) has been superceded by [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).