Keyboard input to UTF-32 problem. i want it to be U+1D41A but instead it outputs U+D41A
im trying to make a keyboard injection converter thing, that takes an input and outputs it into a certain unicode. This is my first time jumping into unicodes so i don't really know anything about this.
And the problem im having is that i want it to output
U+1D41A 

but instead it outputs
U+D41A

i also tried using a lookup table but it still does the same thing.
Here is my code.
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

HHOOK hHook;

char32_t to_math_bold(wchar_t c)
{
    if (c >= L'A' && c <= L'Z') {
        return static_cast<char32_t>(c + 0x1D4D0 - L'A');
    } 
    else if (c >= L'a' && c <= L'z') {
        return static_cast<char32_t>(c + 0x1D41A - L'a');
    } 
    else if (c >= L'0' && c <= L'9') {
        return static_cast<char32_t>(c + 0x1D7E0 - L'0');
    }
    return static_cast<char32_t>(c);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
        DWORD vkCode = p->vkCode;

        WCHAR buffer[4] = {0}; // Increased size for possible multi-byte characters

        BYTE keyState[256];
        GetKeyboardState(keyState);

        int result = ToUnicode(vkCode, p->scanCode, keyState, buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(WCHAR), 0);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            wchar_t typedChar = buffer[0];

            std::wcout << L"Typed: " << typedChar << L" (U+" << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(typedChar) << L")\n";

            char32_t boldChar = to_math_bold(typedChar);

            if (boldChar != typedChar)
            {
                std::wcout << L"Converted to Math Bold: " << static_cast<wchar_t>(boldChar) << L" (U+" << std::hex << boldChar << L")\n";

                INPUT input;
                input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                input.ki.wVk = 0;                     // No virtual key code needed for Unicode
                input.ki.wScan = boldChar;            // Math bold character
                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; // Send Unicode character
                input.ki.time = 0;
                input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::wcout << L"ToUnicode failed with error code: " << GetLastError() << L"\n";
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
}

void Unhook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
}

int main()
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Unhook();
    return 0;
}



Step through the code in the debugger, so that you can watch the content of the variables as the code is running. That should lead you to at least the location where the problem is happening, and most likely let you see why it is happening as well. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn - you're dealing with just a few lines of relatively straightforward code, which means you can step through rather quickly. There's no better tool for solving logic problems with code than the debugger, and it's never too early to start learning to use it.

The fundamental problem here is the WCHAR and wchar_t are 16 bit integers, and U+1D41A does not fit into 16 bits. For the same reason SendInput is not capable of sending true Unicode, it is sending a 16 bit value. I'm not sure how you are supposed to handle character code bigger than 16 bits with SendInput, maybe you have to send two UTF-16 words (I'm just guessing).

This might help explain how you encode a 32 bit value as two 16 bit values using UTF-16.

You can send non-BMP as two UTF-16 surrogates.  I don't have a C++ example but here's a Python example that I've tested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205935/235698

@john "SendInput is not capable of sending true Unicode" - yes, it can. You just have to give it UTF-16 surrogates, as you surmised. Here is a C++ example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863

@RemyLebeau 'true Unicode' was not a very accurate phrase to use. I meant not capable of sending Unicode character codes directly.

@john not Unicode codepoints directly, no. But codepoints encoded in UTF-16, yes.

i figured out how to do it now, thanks! I ended up combining my code using the c++ example @john gave after reading about the surrogates, i didn't expect it to be THAT complicated i wanted to make this program for a joke and ended up learning about unicodes.

@Harley Glad to help. Not sure where you are going as a programmer, but if you take it up as a profession then being able to learn independently is one of the most important skills you will have.
